# Creating Event Procedure in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have tried to create the event procedure, but It returns zero irrespective of my selection.
I have two tables, which are correctly joined, and below is the code that has an issue. 
First, "MsgBox Me.Technology" is returning my selection value eg. Python, Java, but "MsgBox rs!ProjEmployeeID" is returning 0 all times. Help me troubleshoot the code. Thank you. I want it to return Project Employee ID like 1, 2, 3

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Technology_AfterUpdate()
 MsgBox Me.Technology
 Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ProjEmployeeID FROM Project WHERE Technologies = Trim('" & Forms!Form_employee_by_technologies!Technology & "')")
 rs.AddNew
 MsgBox rs!ProjEmployeeID
 Dim strDocName As String
Dim strWhere As String
    strDocName = "Technology"
    strWhere = "[EmployeeID] =" & rs!ProjEmployeeID
    DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewReport, , strWhere, acWindowNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using Trim? If you need it then use it on the field before field is surrounded by apostrophes in concatenation. Have you step debugged?

Comment: What is the `rs.AddNew` doing in the code??? I suspect that this is the issue.

Comment: The issue was rs.AddNew                                                                                       Thank you all, you helped much Trim was for removing white spaces